# Angular 2 add javascript lib

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to add this library to my angular webapp

```
<script src="https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js"></script>
```

But i havent been able to do it. What would be the correct way to integrate a javascript library?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue is that Typescript won't understand the types used by the library because it's in JavaScript form.  Take a look on this github site for the library you want to load and then you can install the type signatures:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped